# Can I temporarily change a user's role in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need to grant users a specific role (Editor, Administrator, etc.) along with all its capabilities on the fly in Wordpress, but I don't want to update their role in the database (so that the next time they come back, they will have their original role). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53230/temporary-capability-for-current-user-can

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but do I have to manually override all of their capabilities? Can I easily return all of the capabilities for a given role with this? For instance, if I want to set a user's capabilities to that of an Editor, do I have to manually set all of the capabilities related to Editors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'override_caps' );

function override_caps($allcaps){

    if( ... ){ // When to override caps

        $role_name = 'administrator';
        $role = get_role($role_name); // Get the role object by role name
        $allcaps = $role->capabilities;  // Get the capabilities for the role
        $allcaps[$role_name] = true;     // Add role name to capabilities

    }

    return $allcaps;

}
```